# Substitute text on one line with capture group from previous line?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, global-command

Suppose I've copied a bunch of lines of boilerplate code that I need to copy multiple times over, and then change in two separate places, in the same way:

```
  it 'includes sessions#new' do
    expect(get: '/sign_in').to route_to('devise/sessions#new')
  end
```

so I'm gonna copy this seven or eight times, and I need to change `sessions#new` on both lines. So if I go through and change the first line of each statement manually, I end up with this:

```
  it 'includes sessions#new' do
    expect(get: '/sign_in').to route_to('devise/sessions#new')
  end

  it 'includes sessions#destroy' do
    expect(get: '/sign_in').to route_to('devise/sessions#new')
  end

  it 'includes passwords#new' do
    expect(get: '/sign_in').to route_to('devise/sessions#new')
  end

  it 'includes passwords#create' do
    expect(get: '/sign_in').to route_to('devise/sessions#new')
  end
```

Now, I'd like to change all the second-line instances of `sessions#new` to the corresponding string from the previous line.

I know I can do this with a long, convoluted multi-line substitution command:

```
:%s/^\(  it 'include \)\(\w\+#\w\+\)\(.*' do\n.*'\)\(\w\+#\w\+\)\(.*\)$/\1\2\3\2\5
```

What I'd like to know is if it's possible to do something comparable and perhaps a little more compact with the `:global` command, like this:

```
:g/includes \(\w\+#\w\+\)/+1s/sessions#new/\1
```

Unfortunately, the above command doesn't work, because the `\1` capture group isn't available to the `:g` command (and anyway, the `:s` command probably thinks it's for *it*).

Is there any way to get this done, or am I stuck with Option 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, to capture groups in the `:g` command and then run an `:s` command, that uses those captured groups. You would have to do it manually, something like this perhaps:

```
g/includes/exe "norm! yi'"|+s/sessions#new/\=split(getreg('"'))[1]/
```

This uses the `:g` command to mark all "includes" lines and on each include line, it will use the [i' textobject](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#i%27) to capture the quoted string and copy it into the unnamed register. Then on the following line, it will execute an `:s` command, search for `sessions#new` and replaces it with the second word in the unnamed register. (using `split()` to access only the second half of the whitespace separated part in the register)

Answer (score 2):

Well, for given sample, the substitute command can be simplified

```
:%s,\vincludes ([^']+).*\n.*/\zs[^']+,\1
```

- `,` is used as delimiter here, so that `/` doesn't need escaping
- `\v` is very magic, so that capturing groups and `+` don't need escaping
- `\zs` set start of match, so that string up to that need not be captured and back-referenced
- `[^']+` will capture all non `'` characters
- `.*/` will consume everything up to last `/` in the line as `*` is greedy